# django no module named wiki

Tags: python, django

Okay, so I am following along with a tutorial about how to make a wiki with django for practice. I'm using Python 2.7 with Django 1.6.4. I am trying to run the server so I can refresh a page but I am all of a sudden getting the error `"ImportError: No module named wiki."`

I've searched through all the answers on here and what's strange is that I have a subdirectory in my project called Wiki that has an **__init__.py** file inside it. Here is what my directory looks like:

```
wikicamp (project)
    wiki
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
    wikicamp
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    dbsqlite3
    manage.py
```

My **settings.py** file `INSTALLED_APPS` looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'wiki',
```

)

I have tried it both as `'wikicamp.wiki`', and as `'wiki'`, and I get the same thing with both. It won't even let me start the development server, I get that error when I type `python manage.py runserver`. I have made sure I am in the correct directory.

Here is all the info I get from that:

```
    PS C:\python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\wikicamp> python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)

  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')

  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)

  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)

  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)

  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)

ImportError: No module named wiki
```

Comment: Can you `runserver` without the `'wiki'` app added to your **settings.py**? What happens?

Comment: Good idea, I hadn't thought of trying that. It runs just fine when I comment it out.

Comment: How did you create the app? Did you `django-admin.py startapp wiki`?

Comment: Yep. I just ran a `python manage.py startapp wiki` command.

Comment: And you have a `BASE_DIR` specified in your **settings.py**?

Comment: This is what's showing in my settings file: `import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Comment: And I added `.py` to the end of all of your python files above. Can you verify that they all (especially **__init__.py**) include the `.py` file extension?

Comment: Thanks. And yeah, they all have two files, a `.py` and a `.pyc` version.

Comment: where exactly did you get the error? I mean did you check the log ? In which line did you get? No offense but I am not clear where did you got the error, in settings or else where? Sometimes I get this kind of error in for importing like, for example: "from wikicamp.wiki.models import foo", actually it was "from wiki.models import foo"

Comment: I get the error right in PowerShell. Whenever I try to run the server it doesn't work. Updating the o.p. to include the actual info I get.

Comment: `PS C:\python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\wikicamp` <-- OK, that could be a problem. Your project should be in some other part of the directory tree, such as your home directory, and definitely not in Django's `bin` directory. As a rule, you shouldn't be putting things in Django's installation directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am following the same tutorials which you were learning from. You just need to go to your wikicamp/url.py file and edit the `patterns` dict as:

```
r'^wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/edit/$', 'wiki.views.edit_page'
```

instead of:

```
r'^wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/edit/$', 'wikicamp.wiki.views.edit_page'
```